# Find the Maximum difference between two Same Numbers in an unsorted array of integers in best Time Complexity [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

```
static int solution(int[] A) {
    int N = A.length;
    int result = 0;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        List<Integer> list = map.getOrDefault(A[i], new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(i);
        map.put(A[i], list);

    }
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> list = map.get(entry.getKey());
        Collections.sort(list);
        result = Math.max(result, (list.get(list.size() - 1) - list.get(0)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

> With this above solution we can solve the problem but it is not O(N) time complexity. So I am looking for an optimized solution for this problem in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> //            Collections.sort(list);//Removing this line makes O(NlogK) to O(N) time complexity

```
  static int solution(int[] A) {
    int N = A.length;
    int result = 0;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        List<Integer> list = map.getOrDefault(A[i], new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(i);
        map.put(A[i], list);

    }
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> list = map.get(entry.getKey());
        result = Math.max(result, (list.get(list.size() - 1) - list.get(0)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is loop through all elements and keep track of only first and last occurence as follow:

```java
class Pair<F, S> {
    F first;
    S second;
    constrcutor(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

    static int solution(int arr[]) {

        // Pair.first will contain the first occurrence and Pair.second will contain the last occurrence of number
        HashMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> minMaxMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            Pair<Integer, Integer> existingValue = minMaxMap.get(arr[index]);
            if (existingValue == null) {
                minMaxMap.put(arr[index], new Pair<Integer, Integer>(index, index));
            } else {
                existingValue.second = index; // update the Pair.second to latest value.
            }
        }

        int result = 0;
        for (Pair<Integer, Integer> pair : minMaxMap.values()) {
            int difference = pair.second - pair.first;
            if (difference > result) {
                result = difference;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In your solution, since we are using list, it requires more memory in case the array contains a lot of duplicate element. By avoiding list, you can even reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: Which Pair? Are you talking about javafx.util.Pair?It is the part of the javafx.base module, and  you need to download the JavaFX SDK to your machine, as it is no longer part of the Java JDK anymore.

Comment: You can add a Pair class of your own with 5 lines of code. You won't need to download anything extra.

Comment: @Sibin, added code for Pair.

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks like an efficient solution - it doesn't use any collections and doesn't need to loop through all values. It checks for pair at the maximum distance (same numbers at both array ends), then maximum distance-1 and so on, only until the pair is found.

```
static int solution(int[] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (A[j] == A[j + A.length - i])
                return A.length - i;
        }
    }
    return -1; //-1 stands for no equal numbers
}
```

Comment: Time Complexity for this solution O(N^2) which is not better than what is mentioned in the question.

Comment: No, it's much more efficient. It is difficult to say in terms of O notation because it's efficiency depends not only on array length but also of number of possible inputs, that is a range of inputs that can be input at each array index). I did the tests and for example if we have constant range of possible random inputs (ex. 10 000) and long random arrays (ex range 100 000 - 10 000 000) the efficiency will be O(1) for that range. I also tested against method mentioned in the question and with 100000 random array my method usually scores below 5ms and method from the question above 200